# Magento 2 Remove Items From Cart With Qty = 0

Tags: magento2, cart

In Magento 1.9, when we added multiple products into the cart, we can removing them by entering 0 in the Quantity field for each product, and then click on Update Basket button, then those products with 0 in quantity fields will be removed from the shopping cart.

But it seems this feature has been removed in Magento 2. It's not allowed to enter a 0 in the Qty field any more. Can we turn this feature on?

[image]

Comment: You can easily remove the product by click on remove button then why you need this/

Comment: I know that. But I still want this feature to remove a product with qty = 0. It's easier if customer wants to remove multiple products, so they don't need to click remove button 10 times, and avoiding webpage to load 10 times.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing this validation "{validate-greater-than-zero':true}" from quantity field.

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I needed.  Although, I didn't outright remove that line, but changed true --> false in and it did the job perfectly.  For anyone looking for this file it's in Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/item/default.phtml. 

Thanks again @cms.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, this feature is needed to remove multiple items at once. Seems odd to remove it.